# resources.designer.cs isn't auto-generating. (MonoDevelop beginner)

Tags: c#, android, mono, monodevelop

I'm new to MonoDevelop, I'm learning to build apps to Android. I'm facing a problem in the following tutorial: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/hello_world

This tutorial claims that if I change the resource.xml file, and rebuild the application, There will be an auto- generated code in the resource.designer.cs that influenced by the changes I made in the resource.xml. But the code just stays as it is, without any changes.

What am I missing? Thank you.

**EDIT:**  Nevermind, it is working XD

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue for a while.  If you just delete Resource.Designer.cs it will regenerate correctly.